# Use another Macbook Pro with touchbar as secondary screen

Tags: display

I have two MacBook Pros with touch-bar (with USB-C ports of course), and I wanted to know if there is a chance to use this other MacBook as secondary screen.

I tried to connect them together by plugging USB-C cable in both, but I don't see Arrangement tab in Display settings. Am I missing something, like software solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use iMac as a secondary screen with Mini DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort. Target Display Mode lets you use the built-in display on a supported iMac as an external display for another Mac. To use your iMac as a display in Target Display Mode, connect it to another Mac using the correct cable (see System Requirements below).

[image]

However,

**Connecting two MBPros to create an extended screen won't work.** Use VNC viewer as Remote Desktop if you want else I don't see any option as I am daily working on Apple devices and people has come up with this request many time.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use your MacBook Pro in Target Display Mode nor achieve the same result via a ThunderBolt 3 (USB-C) cable to connect it to the other MacBook Pro.

However, there are other options you can investigate, but I have no personal experience with them. Two of these options are listed below:

- [Air Display](https://avatron.com)
- [Mirroring360](http://www.mirroring360.com)

In summary, they promise to allow users to share their Mac screens on a variety of devices, including other Macs.

Another option which may be worth investigating, is using VNC to share the screen from one MBP to the other - but this may not give you what you want.